# Cannot use the contactEvents method to serialize Event data

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I'm not sure if this is related, but since the [March 6 Release](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/march_2015_release/), I haven't been able to serialize Event data into an Event Data Extension using the Fuel REST API [contactEvents](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/contactEvents.html) method. I've tried using existing Events and even tried creating new Attribute Groups and Events, but get the same behavior each time.

When I make my contactEvents method request:

```
{
    "contactKey": "sam@sample.com",
    "eventDefinitionKey": "CONTACT-EVENT-c350ffa0-cc7b-c52d-3f97-d321cfac7dfd",
    "data": [{
        "id": "FB4CD204-AA75-436B-A7FF-FFC5B9C4E014",
        "name": "Active Preferences",
        "items": [{
            "values": [{
                "name": "Preference",
                "value": "French"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I receive a response:

```
{
   "responseContext":{
      "operationStatus":"OK",
      "schemaType":"Contacts",
      "schemaVersionNumber":417,
      "schemaContextId":"d6e57283-155b-e411-aea6-38eaa71427a1"
   },
   "eventInstanceID":"38a5b11a-de7e-4235-87ff-75bdd09445c5",
   "asyncRequestID":1778,
   "requestServiceMessageID":"80749639-23ad-4fcc-834f-ab70a3fd14ed",
   "serviceMessageID":"e3e4f7bf-c227-4f27-85bd-b0d99ebdad39"
}
```

However, my Event data is not serialized in the Events Data Extension and there is no Activity on the Journey Builder Contacts Administration page. The only way I can fire an Event now is by using Automation Studio.

I have triple-checked all the steps to configure my Event and they are correct. I have done this many times before and it worked without issue, but it appears to have stopped working in the new release.

Can anyone confirm if the contactEvents method still works?

Comment: Hello, I'm still at a complete loss with this one. Can anyone confirm that the contactEvents method is still working? I've put together a set of reproducible steps that demonstrate this method is now broken. Please refer to this short video: http://bit.ly/19880qW

Comment: I've tried the same steps indicated in the video in a different Marketing Cloud account and get the same result :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is being reported as a queue issue that has been resolved. The code you have should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we are experiencing exactly the same issue on the S6 instance with the contactEvents method request:

```
{
"contactKey": "johndoe@mindvalley.com",
"eventDefinitionKey": "CONTACT-EVENT-0fdbc972-bf58-7f3b-01fe-72252a728863",
"data": [{
    "id": "F518156F-D775-45CB-9F09-2F8A11103A0E",
    "name": "silvalifesystem_journey",
    "items": [{
        "values": [
            {
            "name": "email",
            "value": "johndoe@mindvalley.com"                
      }]
    }]
}] }
```

The response is a 200 OK:

```
{ "responseContext": {
"operationStatus": "OK",
"schemaType": "Contacts",
"schemaVersionNumber": 456,
"schemaContextId": "ef71dd0b-bfb9-e311-9b65-80c16e720c48"
},
"eventInstanceID": "c038758c-bca2-40aa-a55c-754848760bb8",
"asyncRequestID": 106,
"requestServiceMessageID": "30dc3549-08a3-4a59-9508-7b455a03841e",
"serviceMessageID": "1b124026-735d-4233-97c5-dc11f6752463"
}
```

However, the contact never got added to the data extension specified in our payload: silvalifesystem_journey and there is no activity in the Journey Builder contact Administration page.

Has this issue been resolved for all instances or s the bug reoccurring?

Thank you,
Dylan

Comment: Dylan, welcome to SFSE. Your post is more like "I have the same problem too.." rather than an answer to the question. you can either ask a new question and link to this one or post your issue as a comment if possible.

Comment: Commenting wasn't possible because of some point limitation. Sorry about that. Posting a new thread seems unnecessary as it is exactly the same issue.